# How to edit the license line in a MediaWiki template

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to know how and and where do I edit a MediaWiki template so that I can add text to the end of the license text. (The "Creative Commons" content, highlighted in Red.) [image: Screengrab of my wiki]

So far I tried to edit several "MediaWiki" including "MediaWiki:License" and "MediaWiki:Footer" but to no avail.

Here's what I would like to do, this is from the actual MediaWiki page:

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That message can be altered from `MediaWiki:Copyright` (and `MediaWiki:Copyright/ar`, etc. for every other language than your default language).

To find out the names (and corresponding MediaWiki namespace pages) for user interface messages, append `?uselang=qqx` to the end of the url, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainpage?uselang=qqx

If you want to keep the message, but change just the license text, that is done in `LocalSettings.php`, using [`$wgRightsText`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRightsText):

```
$wgRightsText = "Open Database license 1.0";
```

(Other license specific settings are listed [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Copyright_variables).)

Comment: Thanks for that. I came across that page (`MediaWiki:Copyright`) but it didn't exactly make sense to me earlier.

Comment: `wikimedia-copyright` is the message key on Wikimedia projects (defined by WikimediaMessages), not on core.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you chose one of the standard licenses, you should only set [`$wgRightsUrl`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRightsUrl) in your `LocalSettings.php`, for instance

```
$wgRightsUrl = 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/';
```